# Highcharts - changing x-axis labels with rangeselector

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use the highstock graph. I want to update the xAxis labels according to the range which is selected from the rangeselector. eg. if it's a 1-year graph, i want the ticks to be at the end of each month with labels as Jan-12,Feb-12 etc.(by default it shows each month as the beginning of that month). And if it's a monthly graph i want the labels to be positioned at each friday ie. at an interval of 7 days.

Is there a way i can dynamically change which labels are displayed on the axis based on the extremes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tickPositioner (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) or formatter to change labels name http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter